# How do i give boolean status success or not to pendingIntent in broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

i'm developing `addAction` notification from iBeacon, how do i give boolean status success or not to this `actionIntent` from this pendingIntent notification which will received in `onReceive` method in `ActionReceiver.class`
this is the notification method from `MainActivity.class`

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, ActionReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("action", "notif1");
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.th_notif_logo)
                .setTicker("Your Title")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .addAction(R.drawable.ic_petunjuk_icon,"Clue", actionIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
                .setStyle(new Notification.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentIntent(pIntentAction)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build();
```

this is the `onReceive` method in ActionReceiver.class

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action=intent.getStringExtra("action");
        if(action.equals("notif1")){
            SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MYPREFS", MODE_PRIVATE);
            final String nama_tim = preferences.getString("username", "Key not correct");
            InserData(nama_tim, "fsrd");
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),"Action Receiver berhasil masuk",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(action.equals("action2")){

        }
        //This is used to close the notification tray
        Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        context.sendBroadcast(it);
    }
```

so when i got boolean status success or not, i can do something in `MainActivity.class`

```
    if (actionIntent == success){
      //do something
    }
```

really appreciate your help guys..

Comment: So you want to receive the `PendingIntent` action from the notification to `MainActivity` right?

Comment: yess, i just need it's status or anything or ID from ActionReceiver.class in my thought it would be boolean status, but the status MUST success

Comment: Just put boolean with `actionIntent.putExtra() `.

Comment: i have tried, it turns red, could you more elaborate your answer please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `MainActivity.class`

```
Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("action-key"); // Specify the action to your intent.
broadcastIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

// The values you want receive in the BroadcastReceiver.
broadcastIntent.putExtra("key-action", "notif1");
broadcastIntent.putExtra("key-boolean", true); 

PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT) 
NotificationCompat.Action notificationAction = new NotificationCompat.Action(R.drawable.ic_action, "Action Name", actionIntent)
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"channelId")
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setTicker("Your Title")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle("test")
            .setContentText("test")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .addAction(notificationAction) // Adds an action button to the notification
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent) // Launches the intent when you click the notification. 
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .build();
....

....
// Instead of using your own class receiver, you have to use the default default class receiver if you want your data to reach to your MainActivity.class easily.
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction() == "action") {
                bool result = intent.getBooleanExtra("key-boolean", false); // Your value
            }
        }
    };

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction("action");
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: the whole reason why i'm doing this, i want to listen on click addAction button on notification, so i can put plusCounterClicked() method. but it can not be done in ActionReceiver.class , it must in MainActivity.class

Comment: All written above is in MainActivity.

Comment: i think there's something wrong with the 
PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.
the code its just stop there. there should be something example: PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Comment: @stuck
Indeed, thanks I edited my code.
Anyway, did you manage to work it out?

Comment: the notificationAction is red, somehow its like Notification.Action notificationAction =  ... to work,  and then if i put the action button in there its not work, the notificationAction is never used.  somehow i must put .addAction(R.drawable.ic_petunjuk_icon,"Petunjuk", actionIntent) to show my action button

Comment: oh wait, you put as .setAction(notificationAction) , but it requires minSDK 24, ah wait, i'll try that

Comment: i'm using android 6.0 which is min SDK is 23 , yours is minSDK 24, i can not use that, and also i'm targeting minSDK 19, could you fix your code please  . i can not use .setActions()

Comment: Use the `NotificationCompat` instead of `Notification`.
I've updated the code, it should work by now.
I assume you know how to create a channel, if you don't here's a ref: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: finally, i dont use Notification.Action notificationAction = new Notification.Action(R.drawable.ic_petunjuk_icon, "Petunjuk", actionIntent); instead i use the old style .addAction(R.drawable.ic_petunjuk_icon,"Petunjuk", actionIntent) because i'm targeting minSDK 19, but when im targeting android 8 higher i use yours. but its working as i expected. :) thank you very much. i'll accept your answer, but could be more specific to android 8.  :)

Comment: hey @dr3k , one more, how do i change intent the broadcastIntent to MainActivity on click instead Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent("action"); it does not go to MainActivity

Comment: @stuck Add this intent `PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);` to `.setContentIntent(contentIntent)` on the `NotificationCompat.Builder`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `public static boolean`? Can you explain exactly when do you want your boolean to be `true` or `false`?

Comment: i know public static boolean, but i don't know how to use it in this case, any condition that tell actionIntent received that tells me its true or Toast pop up that tell true too, or maybe when getStringExtra is read and true., i need identification from onReceive method in ActionReceiver.class